# Github Action Deployment on Webserver "error copy file"

Tags: git, github, webserver, scp

I have a Problem with the following yaml file:

```
name: Test and Deploy

on:
  push:
    branches: [ main ]

jobs:
  deploy:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest

    steps:
    - name: Checkout repository
      uses: actions/checkout@v2

    - name: Deploy to webserver
      uses: appleboy/scp-action@master
      with:
        host: ${{ secrets.SERVER_HOST }}
        username: ${{ secrets.SERVER_USERNAME }}
        password: ${{ secrets.SERVER_PASSWORD }}
        source: "."
        target: "/httpdocs/action"
```

When pushing to main i get this Error

```
##[debug]Evaluating condition for step: 'Deploy to webserver'
##[debug]Evaluating: success()
##[debug]Evaluating success:
##[debug]=> true
##[debug]Result: true
##[debug]Starting: Deploy to webserver
##[debug]Loading inputs
##[debug]Evaluating: secrets.SERVER_HOST
##[debug]Evaluating Index:
##[debug]..Evaluating secrets:
##[debug]..=> Object
##[debug]..Evaluating String:
##[debug]..=> 'SERVER_HOST'
##[debug]=> '***'
##[debug]Result: '***'
##[debug]Evaluating: secrets.SERVER_USERNAME
##[debug]Evaluating Index:
##[debug]..Evaluating secrets:
##[debug]..=> Object
##[debug]..Evaluating String:
##[debug]..=> 'SERVER_USERNAME'
##[debug]=> '***'
##[debug]Result: '***'
##[debug]Evaluating: secrets.SERVER_PASSWORD
##[debug]Evaluating Index:
##[debug]..Evaluating secrets:
##[debug]..=> Object
##[debug]..Evaluating String:
##[debug]..=> 'SERVER_PASSWORD'
##[debug]=> '***'
##[debug]Result: '***'
##[debug]Loading env
Run appleboy/scp-action@master
/usr/bin/docker run --name a5c76b983e5a3c391f4e43b5ab2922b38be258_f7934b --label a5c76b --workdir /github/workspace --rm -e "INPUT_HOST" -e "INPUT_USERNAME" -e "INPUT_PASSWORD" -e "INPUT_SOURCE" -e "INPUT_TARGET" -e "INPUT_PORT" -e "INPUT_TIMEOUT" -e "INPUT_COMMAND_TIMEOUT" -e "INPUT_KEY" -e "INPUT_KEY_PATH" -e "INPUT_PASSPHRASE" -e "INPUT_FINGERPRINT" -e "INPUT_USE_INSECURE_CIPHER" -e "INPUT_RM" -e "INPUT_DEBUG" -e "INPUT_STRIP_COMPONENTS" -e "INPUT_OVERWRITE" -e "INPUT_TAR_TMP_PATH" -e "INPUT_PROXY_HOST" -e "INPUT_PROXY_PORT" -e "INPUT_PROXY_USERNAME" -e "INPUT_PROXY_PASSWORD" -e "INPUT_PROXY_PASSPHRASE" -e "INPUT_PROXY_TIMEOUT" -e "INPUT_PROXY_KEY" -e "INPUT_PROXY_KEY_PATH" -e "INPUT_PROXY_FINGERPRINT" -e "INPUT_PROXY_USE_INSECURE_CIPHER" -e "HOME" -e "GITHUB_JOB" -e "GITHUB_REF" -e "GITHUB_SHA" -e "GITHUB_REPOSITORY" -e "GITHUB_REPOSITORY_OWNER" -e "GITHUB_REPOSITORY_OWNER_ID" -e "GITHUB_RUN_ID" -e "GITHUB_RUN_NUMBER" -e "GITHUB_RETENTION_DAYS" -e "GITHUB_RUN_ATTEMPT" -e "GITHUB_REPOSITORY_ID" -e "GITHUB_ACTOR_ID" -e "GITHUB_ACTOR" -e "GITHUB_TRIGGERING_ACTOR" -e "GITHUB_WORKFLOW" -e "GITHUB_HEAD_REF" -e "GITHUB_BASE_REF" -e "GITHUB_EVENT_NAME" -e "GITHUB_SERVER_URL" -e "GITHUB_API_URL" -e "GITHUB_GRAPHQL_URL" -e "GITHUB_REF_NAME" -e "GITHUB_REF_PROTECTED" -e "GITHUB_REF_TYPE" -e "GITHUB_WORKFLOW_REF" -e "GITHUB_WORKFLOW_SHA" -e "GITHUB_WORKSPACE" -e "GITHUB_ACTION" -e "GITHUB_EVENT_PATH" -e "GITHUB_ACTION_REPOSITORY" -e "GITHUB_ACTION_REF" -e "GITHUB_PATH" -e "GITHUB_ENV" -e "GITHUB_STEP_SUMMARY" -e "GITHUB_STATE" -e "GITHUB_OUTPUT" -e "RUNNER_DEBUG" -e "RUNNER_OS" -e "RUNNER_ARCH" -e "RUNNER_NAME" -e "RUNNER_TOOL_CACHE" -e "RUNNER_TEMP" -e "RUNNER_WORKSPACE" -e "ACTIONS_RUNTIME_URL" -e "ACTIONS_RUNTIME_TOKEN" -e "ACTIONS_CACHE_URL" -e GITHUB_ACTIONS=true -e CI=true -v "/var/run/docker.sock":"/var/run/docker.sock" -v "/home/runner/work/_temp/_github_home":"/github/home" -v "/home/runner/work/_temp/_github_workflow":"/github/workflow" -v "/home/runner/work/_temp/_runner_file_commands":"/github/file_commands" -v "/home/runner/work/git_actions_example/git_actions_example":"/github/workspace" a5c76b:983e5a3c391f4e43b5ab2922b38be258
tar all files into /tmp/513600315/AvOsxxCiop.tar
scp file to server.
drone-scp error:  error copy file to dest: ***, error message: Process exited with status 11

2023/03/09 16:46:38 error copy file to dest: ***, error message: Process exited with status 11
##[debug]Docker Action run completed with exit code 1
##[debug]Finishing: Deploy to webserver
```

Is there a way to get more information about the issue. ACTIONS_STEP_DEBUG = true is set in the secrets. When i connect to the server via WinSCP or SSH with the same credentials it works. And i added all possible permissions to the folder "action". Thanks in advance.

Comment: I would enable step debug logging to see if you can a detailed error message that way.
https://docs.github.com/en/actions/monitoring-and-troubleshooting-workflows/enabling-debug-logging#enabling-step-debug-logging

Comment: i added the line in the yaml file. but i don't get more information about the error. still containing exactly the same data than before. or do i miss a the link where i can get more details?

      env:
        ACTIONS_STEP_DEBUG: true

Comment: `ACTIONS_STEP_DEBUG` needs to be added as repo secret for it to correctly work

Comment: i editet the error. there is no specific information that i could use for debugging.  ichecked the logs on the server and they are empty. so i think the problem is somewhere in the connection. sorry, first day using Actions